# Why is the output of a series LC circuit sinusoidal?

Tags: passive-networks

How to analyze this circuit? Why is the voltage across the inductor(red plot) and capacitor(green plot) sinusoidal?

[image]

Comment: Your simulation settings are probably wrong.

Comment: What behavior did you expect?

Comment: Sorry. My question should have been that. How to analyze this circuit? Input is a DC voltage. Sinusoidal varying output for this circuit is something I can't understand.

Comment: Not much to analyze here as it is DC circuit. In steady state the inductor behaves like a wire, the cap behaves as disconnect. The sines you are getting are coming from some wrong simulation settings.

Comment: Because you are simulating an unrealistic circuit. How do you think you could make it more realistic?

Comment: @EugeneSh. - the sine waves are perfectly normal for a perfect battery connected to a perfect L and C.

Comment: Battery switched on at t=0, no resistance therefore steady state sinusoids adding to +12V. Looks fine.

Comment: Well, if the battery is a step source, than yes. In this case it is not a DC circuit anymore.

Comment: @EugeneSh., come on. There is no such thing as a DC source that is DC now, was always DC for any time in the past, and will always be DC forward into the future. If that is the criterion for DC, then there is no such thing at all.

Comment: Everyone is giving you a hard time. The natural behavior of an LC circuit is to resonate at some frequency inversely proportional to the square root of the product of L and C. In the real world, the resonance will damp out over time, depending primarily on the series resistance of the inductor and capacitor. If you provide realistic models of inductor and capacitor, which include non-zero series resistance, you will see that the sinusoid will damp out over time. Do not forget about this. This is what an LC circuit does when it is not damped.

Comment: @Eugene Sh., assuming initial conditions are zero is quite valid - there should be a statement to the contrary if that were not the case. Otherwise we're looking at the situation where, perhaps, the capacitor is charged to 12V before the simulation starts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Sinusoidal varying output for this circuit is something I can't
>   understand

Consider a large flywheel connected to a non rotating motor via a rubber spring. Everything is at rest then suddenly the motor starts and rapidly reaches (say) 1200 rpm. The rubber spring starts twisting at the rate of 1200 rpm at the motor end but at the flywheel end it has barely moved because of the mass of the flywheel.

Eventually, the flywheel is seen to be turning slowly but gradually, it accelerates and some time later it reaches a speed of 1200 rpm.

What happens next is important. At the instant it reaches 1200 rpm there are many, many twists in the rubber spring and this represents stored energy but motor and flywheel are at the same speed. The rubber spring has no option; it exerts a rotating force on the only thing that can has freedom of movement (the flywheel) and, the flywheel ramps up in speed past 1200 rpm continuing until the rubber spring has exhausted its stored energy.

However, for each turn undone on the spring, the force transmitted by the spring's stored energy gets less and less until finally, when the flywheel has reached 2400 rpm, the spring is undone.

It doesn't stop there because the "problem" the spring now has is that the flywheel is rotating at 2400 rpm whilst the motor is stuck at 1200 rpm. So the rubber spring starts coiling up in the opposite direction, taking energy from the flywheel and slowing it down. Eventually both motor and flywheel are at the same speed but the inductor (ahem spring) has still got stored energy and this stored energy seeks to slow down the capacitor (ahem flywheel).

Eventually all the inductor/spring energy is spent and the capacitorflywheel is at 0V/0 rpm. The process then repeats and it's a sine wave of course.

Losses play a big part and the spring isn't perfect - it gets hot and this saps energy and the flywheel bearings get warm also. So it's a decaying sine wave and eventually the flywheel is continuously rotating at 1200 rpm.

It might help if you examined the voltage peaks you are seeing. I've altered your graph to put on 24V, 12V, 0V and -12V: -

[image]

If you analysed the period of oscillation you'd probably settle on something around 70 us. If you then used the LC formula for a tuned circuit i.e. this one: -

F = \$\dfrac{1}{2\pi\sqrt{LC}}\$

Then, if you plugged in the values for L and C you'd get a frequency of 15.915 kHz and that frequency has a period of 62.8 us. Perfectly normal behaviour for this "perfect" circuit.

Comment: Thank you! Wonderful explanation. I do get an idea of why this behavior is even possible. Your explanation however suits if all we have is a capacitor(say charged to some initial voltage) connected in parallel with inductor. (No voltage source). But when there is a voltage source connected, once the capacitor charges to maximum, the voltage across  inductor would be zero and since the capacitor voltage is equal to supply voltage, current in the circuit would be zero. Why doesn't this end the process of continuous charging and discharging?

Comment: No that's missing the entire point of my flywheel story. When the capacitor reaches 12V there is still current in the inductor and this continues pushing the voltage up on the cap till it reaches 24 volts. Current in an inductor is the time integral of voltage divided by inductance and, at the time when Vcap = 12V, the voltage across L may be zero but the time integral of voltage certainly isn't and current flow is maximum - this is stored energy that the inductor has to supply to the cap and push it up to 24V.

Comment: When capacitor reaches 12V, the inductor is connected between two sources of equal and opposite voltage. Why would the current not be zero? Could you please explain this?

Comment: The basic fundamental equation that is V equals L di/dt. Integrate both sides to solve for current and you'll find that current is proportional to the time integral of voltage. And, given that up till that point the voltage has been applied only in one direction, the time integral can never be zero. What you are asking implies a resistor and not an inductor. Try googling a picture of v and I of an inductor when ac is applied. Current only ever equals zero when the average accumulated voltage across it is zero.

Comment: Thank you :) I tried simulating the circuit with an inductor and an ac voltage applied to it. The current will be zero when the average voltage is zero. Say if I apply a pulse voltage from 0 to 5V at certain frequency, the average would never be zero. Would current increase indefinitely in this case? I tried simulating this and the result is that current goes on increasing.